# Non-Trivial Elements in the center of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been working on some problems in introductory abstract algebra, and
I came across one that I have been having soome difficulty with. I want to prove
that $S_n$ (the symmetric group of $n$ elements) has only trivial elements
in its center for $n \geq 3$ (i.e. no non-trivial elements).

Take $a \in S_n, a \neq e$ (where $e \in S$ is the identity element). Let
$a = a_1,...,a_k$ be the decomposition of $a$ into disjoint cycles, and let
$a_1 = (b_1,...,b_m)$. I have been told that if I let $m \geq 3,$ and
set $\beta = (b_1,b_2),$ Then $a^{-1} \beta a = (b_1a,b_2a) = (b_2,b_3) \neq
\beta$, and thus $a \notin Z(S_n).$ I need some help working on this
for the $m = 2,1$ cases. Any recommendations on finding the $\beta$ for
these cases?

Comment: Note that if $a$ is not the identity then at least one cycle has length $>1$, so you can assume $m>1$. For $m=2$ try $\beta=(b_1,c)$ where $c\neq b_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

The symmetric group $S_{n}$ acts on the set $\{1, …, n\}$ by permuting its elements.

Let $n \geq 3$. Suppose $\phi \in S_{n}$ but $\phi \neq e$, where $e$ is the identity.

WLOG $\phi(1)=2$. Now let $\psi(2)=3$ and $\psi(1)=1$ Then $\psi(\phi(1))=\psi(2)=3 \neq 2 = \phi(1)= \phi(\psi(1))$.

Note that $\phi$ is a generic permutation (bijection) where our only condition is that it not be the identity, i.e. all we know is it maps $1$ to $2$. We are able to construct a permutation that does not commute (with our generic bijection) and so $e$ is the only element in the center.